# c# String.Compare vs String.CompareOrdinal

Tags: c#, string

In C#, is `String.CompareOrdinal(strA, strB)` equivalent to `String.Compare(strA, strB, StringComparison.Ordinal)`?

I checked the document at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx and it doesn't mention this.

Comment: I'm not actually seeing any answers in those dups that actually address this specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both do the same thing. You can follow the source from https://referencesource.microsoft.com

1. [public static int CompareOrdinal(String strA, String strB)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0601c3adfb08dab2.html)
2. Calls [private unsafe static int CompareOrdinalHelper(String strA, String strB)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8711fff131bc4d0e.html)

and

1. [public static int Compare(String strA, String strB, StringComparison comparisonType)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/0be9474bc8e160b6.html)
2. Calls [private unsafe static int CompareOrdinalHelper(String strA, String strB)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8711fff131bc4d0e.html)

The code paths are nearly identical

In fact the only diffrence is the later has a quick check, so if you have *Instruction OCD* you can statistically save your self a couple of cycles maybe

```
   if ((strA.m_firstChar - strB.m_firstChar) != 0)
   {
        return strA.m_firstChar - strB.m_firstChar;
   }
```